# Globally disable Tensorflow asserts?

Tags: python, tensorflow, testing

Is there an option in Tensorflow that I can set to ignore all the `Assert` operations I've added to my `Graph`?

The use case I'm thinking about is adding a bunch of Asserts using [`tf.contrib.framework.with_shape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/framework/with_shape), and then toggling a flag in my configuration file, `config.fast` to decide whether I should skip these Asserts during training.

Normally I'd choose whether to generate the `Asserts` in the first place based on whether `config.fast` is set, but when using `with_shape` it seems more convenient to chain this option to my Tensors without looking at my `config.fast`.

Comment: You could have something like `check_asserts = tf.placeholder_with_default(True, ())` and then wrap the assertions like `tensor = tf.cond(check_asserts, lambda: tf.contrib.framework.with_shape(shape, tensor), lambda: tf.identity(tensor))`... then you could pass `check_asserts: False` in the `feed_dict` to skip asserts on run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using something similar to @jdehesa's comment suggestion but with a branched factory function instead of a `tf.cond`.

```
def make_maybe_with_shape(skip_asserts):
    if skip_asserts:  # identity
        return lambda expected_shape, tensor: tensor
    else:
        return lambda expected_shape, tensor: tf.contrib.framework.with_shape(
                expected_shape, tensor)
```